# Export or save html source including iFrame's html

Tags: html, iframe, firebug, firefox-addon

In FireBug the HTML view displays the full html of the page including the html of the iFrames. Is there a way to save this same html view or using another FF extension to save the full html? Meaning the saved file will have the html, body and the rest of the dom for the iFrames. I know I can view and save the individual iFrames' HTML but I want everything in a single file.

Answer (score 0):

You can crawl the DOM for all the iframes and then do httpRequest to capture the dom from each url in the src attribute of the iframe.

Comment: Like I said, I can do this manually. I want to capture everything is one shot. Think of what Firebug is showing in HTML view. Now save it.

Comment: To capture it in one shot you need a scripting language live VB or you can have a web server do the work for you like PHP or ColdFusion.  Even though you need it in one shot, the DOM has to be crawled so you can get an array of iframes.  I have done this with VB and has worked well.  What scripting language are you comfortable with?

Comment: I use .NET. I was looking for a tool that does the work for me. I mean if Firebug is showing all the HTML, I wish they had an export or save option in there.